# Doing each in Ruby, how to place a br every n items

Tags: ruby

Given I have 10 items to iterate and I want to place a br every 3 of them like this example. How can I do this in Ruby?

```
1
2
3
<br>
4
5
6
<br>
7
8
9
<br>
10
```

Comment: Interesting: 2 of the 3 downvoted answers used the XHTML tag `<br/>` and all the upvoted answers used the HTML tag `<br>`. Well I just said it was interesting..

Comment: @Zabba: Maybe the former are Rails developers, while the latter are non-web developers who specialize in Plain Old Ruby Objects, and are more familiar with the language and its functional programming capabilities.

Comment: I just tried to be faithful to the question. I think those who wrote `<br/>` were downvoted (not by me) because they do not give what is asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
(1..10).each_slice(3){|a| puts '<br>' unless a[0] == 1; puts a}
```

**Solution 2** (ruby 1.9.2)

```
(1..10).chunk{|i| i.%(3).zero?}.each{|r, a| puts(a, *('<br>' if r))}
```

**Solution 3**

```
puts (1..10).each_slice(3).map{|a| a.unshift('<br>')}.flatten.drop(1)
```

**Solution 4** (ruby 1.9.2)

```
puts ['<br>'].product((1..10).each_slice(3).to_a).flatten.drop(1)
```

**Solution 5**

```
puts (1..10).each_slice(3).with_object([]){|a, aa| aa.push('<br>', *a)}.drop(1)
```

**Solution 6**

```
puts (1..10).map{|i| i.%(3).zero?? [i, '<br>'] : i}
```

**Solution 7**  (ruby1.9.2)

```
puts (1..10).to_a.
  tap{|a| a.length.downto(1){|i| a.insert(i, '<br>') if i.%(3).zero?}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 (1..10).each do |i|
   puts i
   puts '<br>' if i % 3 == 0
 end
```

Comment: -1: Procedural code, and doesn't use `.zero?`. Not as bad as some answers, but a 33K user should do better.

Comment: @Andrew: well, without list comprehensions (which Ruby doesn't have) a functional solution might be rather clunky. Sawa tried it and it's ... just OK. Perhaps you could post something?  If you are accusing me of not knowing about `.zero?`, you are correct, I didn't. But now that I do, I still don't like it in this case. It's *more source characters* and certainly harder to read.  In any case, I would encourage you again to post your ideas.  Answers on SO live forever and if it's any good it will eventually get votes.

Comment: +1 for being a whole lot clearer than every "properly functional" example posted.  If functional must be as complicated as it's represented by the others here, give me procedural code anyday.

Comment: @cHao: Ruby isn't ideal for pure functional programming, but there's usually a happy middle that's nicer than the full-on procedural solution here (not to hate on DigitalRoss — I agree this code is more readable than the pure version, which is an extremely valuable quality). See my answer for what I consider to be a very concise but still declarative version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575172/doing-each-in-ruby-how-to-place-a-br-every-n-items/5585501#5585501

Comment: @Chuck: Yeah, i upvoted yours too.  :)  Code i can understand > code that's "pure" or "proper".

Answer (score 4):

```
>> (1..10).each_slice(3).to_a.map{|x|x.join("\n")}.join("\n<br>\n")
=> "1\n2\n3\n<br>\n4\n5\n6\n<br>\n7\n8\n9\n<br>\n10"
```

Comment: +1 For a properly functional solution. Note that the `.map` is not necessary.

Comment: @Phrogz, why isn't the `map` necessary? Without it the output is `1\n<br>\n2\n<br>\n3\n<br>...`. (Ruby 1.8.7)

Comment: @Zabba Not for me: `ruby-1.8.7-p330> (1..10).each_slice(3).map{|x|x.join}.join("<br>") #=> "123<br>456<br>789<br>10"` (simplified for clarity)

Comment: @Phrogz: Surely it's the `to_a` that is unnecesary, not the `map`.

Comment: @Chuck Holy crap, of course that's what I meant, as evidenced by the code. I am shocked that I read that in two separate comments and completely didn't notice the mistake. Thank you for bringing clarity to my clearly-confusing comment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question well, he didn't say that the elements would always be (1..10), and most answers I saw here are only valid for this specific case, since they rely on the value of the element, not in the index. A more generic solution that would work not only when `array = (1..10).to_a`, but with any array of any size is this:

```
array.each_with_index do |o, i| 
  puts o
  puts '<br>' if i % 3 == 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..10).each do |i| 
    puts i
    if (i % 3 == 0) 
      puts "<br/>"
    end
end
```

Comment: -1: Procedural code, doesn't do `puts ... if foo`, doesn't use `.zero?`. Also, but this isn't part of why I downvoted, is Ruby is normally indented two, not four, spaces.

Comment: I am just starting out with Ruby myself. Why does this matter?

Comment: Wouldn't you want other people learning Ruby to see examples of good Ruby code, not examples of average Ruby code?

Comment: You haven't demonstrated what makes it average, aside from some syntactic shortcuts and an aversion for procedural code. I'm curious as to why those things actually matter, aside from personal preference.

Comment: What would you consider "average"?

Answer (score 0):

For printing, I like a combination of kurumi's and DigitalRoss's:

```
array.each_slice(3) {|elems| puts elems.join("\n"), '<br>' }
```

It's pretty declarative and very straightforward.

Comment: That will give an extra `<br>` at the end. All the impurity you see is to get rid of this extra `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts(
  (1..10)
  .each_with_index
  .map { |s, i| i % 3 == 2 ? [s, '<br>'] : s }
  .flatten
  .map(&:to_s)
  .join("\n")
)
```

- This doesn't depend on the initial values being integers.
- `#each_with_index()` with no block returns a generator, which means you can `#map` the results.
- `#flatten` is used to move the '`<br>`' back in-line. You could just modify the string `s` instead like this: `"#{s}#{i % 3 == 2 ? "\n<br>" : nil}"` if you don't like the `#flatten` or you can't `#flatten` for some reason (e.g. you are using nested arrays already).
- The final `#map` is to make sure everything is a string before joining. If you get rid of the `#flatten` as mentioned above, then you don't need this.

Answer (score -2):

Something not so ruby-esque

```
k = 3
while k < array.size
    arrays.insert(k,"<br />")
    k += 4
end
p array
```

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest do a `for(i=0;i<length;i++) { if (i%3) //put br }`

Comment: Sorry.. I misread.. However except the syntex --- the logic is same.. Not sure why -1..

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but perhaps because the syntax and logic are both wrong for Ruby. In ruby, `i%3` is always a truthy value. (`!!0` is not false, unlike in JavaScript.)