# How to extract every third id from child ids, Rails ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am getting this kind of array from query in Rails console:

```
 ←[1m←[35mCategory Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT id FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`ancestry` = '56'
=> [57, 64, 73, 74, 80, 94, 102, 103, 120]
```

I want to be able extract each third id from there and insert into other object.

I come up with something like this, It may work, but how can I create this to work dynamicaly, and recalculate every third value of the array?

**This is first array:**

```
  @ids_to_exclude = [73,94,120]
```

How can I calculate each third ? Using some array element id's like in Java where array first element is with 0 position and each next is +1 ?

**This is second array:**

```
@except_every_third= @category('created_at DESC').where('id NOT in (?)', @ids_to_exclude)
```

Is there some guide or example that You can share with me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689186/how-do-you-select-every-nth-item-in-an-array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575172/doing-each-in-ruby-how-to-place-a-br-every-n-items

Comment: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/get-every-nth-member-ruby

Comment: @devanand I used your first suggestion, but I got such error see in description. And also is that answer couldn't be too old ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this useful

```
require "pp"

pp [57, 64, 73, 74, 80, 94, 102, 103, 120].each_slice(3).to_a.map { | e | 
  # e.reverse.drop(1) 
  e.drop(1) 
}.flatten
```

Comment: Then how I can implement this inside controller ?

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds just take the result from first statement and use all after each_slice ...